# How does python bottle framework install routing handler through decorator?

Tags: python, url-routing, wsgi, bottle

An example for installing routing handler under python bottle framework is as follow:

```
from bottle import Bottle, run
app = Bottle()

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

run(app, host='localhost', port=8080)
```

The above code will route "localhost:8080/hello" to page showing "Hello World!"(handled by function hello).
I wonder how this install process can be done?
How can the framework know function "hello" uses "app.route" as its decorator, and thus dispatch the incoming request to that function?

Comment: You don't seem to have any idea how decorators work. "How can the framework know function "hello" uses "app.route" as its decorator" - simply because the decorator is called with the function as an argument, thus it can store it, access it, even modify it, whatever. I'd recommend reading the official decorator tutorial before asking any other decorator-related questions.

Comment: Maybe either my example or my statement is not very good, but my point is that how can the framework find those function install with a particular decorator.

Comment: At the beginning, I thought there's any odd feature of python decorator that can find the "installed function" from the decorator.
But through @vaultah 's solution, I see it just use some way to parse all function signature for find them.

Comment: Well, as I said, reading the decorator tutorial should have cleared up that confusion. Also, with most python libraries (read: all except the ones written in C), you can just browse the source and find out exactly what they're doing. And no, it does not "parse the function signature", it simply _stores a reference to the actual function_, as a function in python is just another object.

Comment: So @l4mpi you mean the code dealing with install routing is not inside yieldroutes?

Comment: As said in the answer, that is only done in special cases. Your code above simply generates a `Route` instance which contains a reference to your `hello` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A name of a function doesn't mean anything to Bottle, **but** only as long as you provide a path (or paths) to `route` decorator.

Arguments to [`Route`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.Route)'s constructor include `callback` and `rule`, where `callback` is your function and `rule` is a path string.

If one or more paths were provided, the Bottle will simply create a `Route` instance for every path.

Function name **only** comes into play, if you don't provide a single path to `route`. Bottle will then generate possible paths from a function's signature (see the [source](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/_modules/bottle.html#yieldroutes) for [`yieldroutes`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.yieldroutes)) and create a `Route` instance for each one of them.

The related part from [`Bottle.route`'s source](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/_modules/bottle.html#Bottle.route):

```
for rule in makelist(path) or yieldroutes(callback):
    for verb in makelist(method):
        verb = verb.upper()
        route = Route(self, rule, verb, callback, name=name,
                      plugins=plugins, skiplist=skiplist, **config)
        self.add_route(route)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for help. At the first, I thought the install routing code is inside wsgiref module. Now, I can further trace how the yieldroutes works.